# How to hide the mouse cursor in java applet?

Tags: java

I want to replace the default cursor with an hand image, so how to hide the default cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Cursor Image:

```
setCursor (Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

User defined Image:

```
  Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  Image image = toolkit.getImage("icons/handwriting.gif");
  Cursor c = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image , newPoint(mainPane.getX(),
     mainPane.getY()), "img");
  mainPane.setCursor (c);
```

[Sample Source](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj_hourglass_cursor/HourglassCursorExample.zip)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Class Cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html) and the `setCursor()` method of any [component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setCursor%28java.awt.Cursor%29) class.

For exactly what you are looking to do I would call `setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR))` on the component for which you want the hand cursor to appear.

This page contains some sample code for your reference: http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/awt/ChangeCursor.shtml